# Is it possible to dynamically change the 'to' value of a scale with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wonder if it is possible to dynamically change the maximum value of a scale with another scale with tkinter.

I have an example with two scale, where the first scale is `sc_maxVal` with the variable `maxVal` which is the maximum value of the second scale.

I'm able to set it in the first place, but I don't know how to change the `to` argument of `sc_var` while the script is running with `sc_max`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
    
mainApp = tk.Tk()
   
mainApp.title("Windows")
mainApp.geometry("800x600")
    
maxVal = tk.DoubleVar()
maxVal.set(20)
    
var = tk.DoubleVar()
var.set(int(maxVal.get()/2))
    
sc_max = tk.Scale(mainApp, label= 'maxVal', from_= 10, to= 40, orient= tk.HORIZONTAL, length= 500, variable= maxVal).pack()
sc_var = tk.Scale(mainApp, label= 'var', from_= 1, to= int(maxVal.get()), orient= tk.HORIZONTAL, length= 500, variable= var).pack()
    
mainApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to just use math to translate the value that you read from the "dynamic" scale to the value that you want in context?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm afraid it's not possible in my context, the problem is really how to change the value after I set it

Comment: It’s not really clear what the problem is. You can change just about any attribute of any widget at any time. Are you familiar with the `configure` method? Are you aware you can have a function called whenever the value changes?

Comment: @GaszokS You should probably post an answer to your quetion. It makes a little more sense than putting the answer in the question, and it will enable other users to know that the question has been satisfactorily answered, without having to read the whole question.

Comment: Good Idea, just did it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of Sylvester Kruin.

The main loop has to be replaced by something like that

```py
while True:
    mainApp.update()
    if you_want_to_change_the_to_value:
        sc_var.config(to=your_value)
```

I also figured out that we have to put the sc_var.pack() in the loop.
It gives us the script

```py
import tkinter as tk

mainApp = tk.Tk()


mainApp.title("Windows")
mainApp.geometry("800x600")


maxVal = tk.DoubleVar()
maxVal.set(40)

changement = int(maxVal.get())

var = tk.DoubleVar()
var.set(int(maxVal.get()/2))


sc_max = tk.Scale(mainApp, label= 'maxVal', from_= 10, to= 40, orient= tk.HORIZONTAL, length= 500, variable= maxVal).pack()
sc_var = tk.Scale(mainApp, label= 'var', from_= 1, to= int(maxVal.get()), orient= tk.HORIZONTAL, length= 500, variable= var)



while True:
    sc_var.pack()
    mainApp.update()

    sc_var.config(to=int(maxVal.get()))
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `root.update()` in a `while True` loop. You should look at tracing tkinter variables instead. Try this: `maxVal.trace("w", lambda *args: print(maxVal.get()))`

Comment: @TheLizzard What does the `trace` attribute of a `tkinter` variable do? And how should it be used in an application with a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a scale to call a function when its value changes. In that function you can use the `configure` method to configure the other scale.

You also make a very common error in calling `pack` in the same statement that you create the widget. You need to separate them, or else the variable you're assigning to will be set to `None` since `.pack(...)` returns `None`.

note: the `command` is passed the new value as an argument.

```
def update_scale(new_max):
    sc_var.configure(to=new_max)

sc_var = tk.Scale(...)
sc_max = tk.Scale(..., command=update_scale)

sc_var.pack()
sc_max.pack()
```

Answer (score -1):

You may want to create a while loop and update the `mainApp` during it. Then, you can change widgets' attributes during the running of the app, without having to have it be triggered by an event or something. For example, use:

```
while True:
    try:
        mainApp.update()
        if you_want_to_change_the_to_value:
            sc_var.config(to=your_value)
    except tkinter.TclError:
        break
```

in place of

```
mainApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have tried and I had the problem that sc_var was a non-type but I figured out that the sc_var.pack() has to be in the loop and not before it. It works now. So thank you very much for your help !